# specify allowed attributes as delimited string in another attribute in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xml-attribute

I am confused about how to design an xml schema, where attributes of an element must have names from those listed in an attribute of another element.

A valid example:

`<A allowedAttributeNames="attrA,attrB">`

`<B attrA="1" attrB="34">`

An invalid example:

`<A allowedAttributeNames="attrA,attrB">`

`<B attrC="72">`

In general, is it true that think separator-separated-lists have poor support in xsd?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in XSD 1.0.

You can do it in XSD 1.1 using assertions. XSD 1.1 is currently supported in recent releases of Xerces and Saxon.